# Writing KStream<String, Map<String, Long>> to a Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-8, apache-kafka-streams

I am reading an from a topic in Kafka and using a streams application to apply changes to my data.

Finally I have a stream looking like this `KStream<String, Map<String, Long>>`. The key (String) is a hash, the value a Map which contains also a key (String) which is just a stemmed word and the value (Long) a count.

It would be great if somebody could point me to a nice way of writing this back to a Kafka topic. I know I cloud convert the Map into a proprietary String representation. But I think that there are more elegant solutions to this problem, e.g. using `Serdes` and apache avro?

Many Thanks
Eduard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Avro or any binary format

A `Map<String,?>` is also represented by a JSON object, which doesn't need to be proprietary. Kafka comes with Jackson, so define an ObjectMapper and write the Map to a JSONObject instance

Comment: It's some time ago, however, I've been searching for a way to directly use a map "kind-of" construct without applying a "manual" serialization. Nevertheless, my search has not been successful thus I ended up serializing it using an Avro schema.